# How do you simplify this expression?

Tags: limits, arithmetic

$$\lim_{h\to0}(\frac{x}{h(x+h+1)} + \frac{1}{x+h+1} - \frac{x}{h(x+1)})$$

I know the answer is $$\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$$

But I can't get there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the lcm of the denominators and simplify: You will get
\begin{align}
\dfrac{x}{h(x+h+1)} + \dfrac{1}{x+h+1} - \dfrac{x}{h(x+1)} & = \dfrac{x(x+1) + h(x+1) - x(x+h+1)}{h(x+1)(x+h+1)}\\
& = \dfrac{x^2+x + hx + h - x^2 - hx - x}{h(x+1)(x+h+1)}\\
& = \dfrac{h}{h(x+1)(x+h+1)}\\
& = \dfrac1{(x+1)(x+h+1)}
\end{align}
Now let $h \to 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Using fraction addition rules, we have

$$\lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{x}{h(x+h+1)} + \frac{1}{x+h+1} - \frac{x}{h(x+1)}\right)\\
=\lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{x(x+1)}{h(x+h+1)(x+1)} + \frac{h(x+1)}{h(x+h+1)(x+1)} - \frac{x(x+h+1)}{h(x+1)(x+h+1)}\right)\\
=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)(x+1)-x(x+h+1)}{h(x+1)(x+h+1)}\\
=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x^2+x+hx+h-x^2-xh-x}{h(x+1)(x+h+1)}\\
=\lim_{h\to0}\frac h{h(x+1)(x+h+1)}=\frac 1{(x+1)^2}$$